# Enable attaching IM flow photo in Contacts

Tags: android

Trying to attach an image to Contacts from my IM flow, doesn't work.

So far we haven't managed to understand why attaching an image of identical size via Gallery works (with an intermediate cropping step), but the image is not picked up from our IM flow. On some phone models (e.g. Sony), this works by default, but on most others it doesn't. We haven't yet been able to find a competing app for which this would work either...

Looking at logs, here is what I get when trying to attach:

```
07-23 15:22:58.001: E/BitmapFactory(15013): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.contacts/cache/tmp/ContactPhoto-IMG_20130723_152249.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-23 15:22:58.021: D/overlay(159): Unset pipe=VG0 dpy=0; Unset pipe=RGB1 dpy=0; 
07-23 15:22:58.202: V/ContactSaveService(15013): Saved contact. New URI: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/3766i49ccee0c897809c7/1674
07-23 15:22:58.232: I/ActivityManager(526): No longer want com.android.providers.calendar (pid 9781): empty #17
07-23 15:22:58.372: D/overlay(159): Set pipe=RGB1 dpy=0; Set pipe=VG0 dpy=0; 
07-23 15:22:58.502: E/ContactSaveService(15013): Failed to write photo: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.contacts/cache/tmp/ContactPhoto-IMG_20130723_152249.jpg because: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.contacts/cache/tmp/ContactPhoto-IMG_20130723_152249.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-23 15:22:58.502: W/CallerInfoCache(824): Previous cache task is remaining.
```